# SwiperJS ломается

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую в проекте библиотеку SwiperJS (https://swiperjs.com/). При уменьшении экрана свайпер ломается, но после перезагрузки адаптируется под размер экрана сам! Как сделать что-бы при уменьшении ширина экрана, он без перезагрузки адаптировался?

```
new Swiper('.swiper-container-banner', {
    autoplay: {
        delay: 4e3,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    breakpoints: {
        320: {
            autoplay: {
                delay: 5e6
            },
        },
        470: {
            autoplay: {
                delay: 4e3
            }
        }

    },
    effect: 'slide',
    init: true,
    on: {
        slideChangeTransitionEnd: function () {
            if ($('.swiper-slide-active .banner-slider__item').attr('data-img').length != 0)
                $(".banner-slider__bg").css("background", 'url("'+$('.swiper-slide-active .banner-slider__item').attr('data-img')+'") 50% center/cover');
        },
    },
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    spaceBetween: 0
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить

```
updateOnWindowResize: true
```

Comment: Работает только при ручном изменении размера окна. А при нажатии на кнопку уменьшения окна, ломается. Так же в обратную сторону, при увеличении окна на весь экран - тоже ломается.

Comment: Тогда стоит попробовать отследить когда курсор выходит за пределы body и снова вызывать функцию инициализации